# macOS Safari problem with (getUserMedia) getting video stream from camera in angular 6 - NotReadableError: The I/O read operation failed

Tags: javascript, angular, macos, safari, getusermedia

Problem is appeared when I try get video stream from camera in `mac` on `safari`.
For get stream I use function `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})`
On `chrome` it works nice, but in `safari` it sometimes throw error:

> NotReadableError: The I/O read operation failed.

[image: console error screen]

The most strange that **it's not stable, it error can appear and after sometime it will be work fine (without changing a code)**...I checked it a lot of times and didn't find dependency why it or work or no.

Another one strange thing that **error shows only in angular**, so I thought that problem could be with `zone.js` but I didn't find solution when trying take out call of function for getting stream from `zone` (for take out from `zone` I used `runOutsideAngular` and `run`).

I tried to use some `npm` libraries like `ngx-webcam`, `ack-angular-webcam` but that didn't help too, when error shows in my code it appears in plugins code too (I guess it cause they use same func to get stream).

So, my long research in internet didn't give appropriate result and I have to ask about advice, solution or at least idea.

**My question**
How to avoid appearing of this error, why it shows not constantly and what is the reason for this error?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Not related to angular, simply running:

```
navigator
  .mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
  .then(
    function(e) {console.log("success",e);},
    function(e){console.log("reject",e);}
  )
```

in a javascript console, and you will see the I/O error, only on Safari. This looks like a WebKit bug.

(i will complete the answer as soon as I found more details).

Comment: I think it related to angular because I didn't note this problem when launched application (that use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()) without angular in safari.
But thanks for your answer.

Comment: So this snippet is working fine on your Safari? not on mine, even with https protocol, I have Safari 12 and tried also on Safari 12.1

Comment: Sorry, maybe something was changed, but a couple day ago I returned to it and it doesn't work anywhere in Safari, but I remember exactly that error doesn't appear sometime ago in webrtc samples but when I execute it in angular environment it was showing. And I still don't have any information about it error.

Comment: found an answer to this? I have a similar error for audio input on ios13

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to zone.js (which is part of angular6)

Try to open polyfills.ts and add

```
   // rtc peer connection patch
   import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-rtc-peer-connection';
   // getUserMedia patch
   import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-user-media.js';
```

after

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

example [here](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/blob/master/Angular-Basic-Video-Chat/src/polyfills.ts). However, it works now sometimes in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem on iOS safari.
The reason is other website was using my camera.
Just turn off all other webrtc sessions and try it again then it will work.

Comment: This is also the case if you are making a regular phonecall with your iPhone. Safari is not able to get access to the cam while the call is active

Answer (score 0):

Works when I put the atribute playsinline in html tag video:

`<video autoplay playsinline class="input_video"></video>`

Answer (score 0):

This error often occurs if the device is being used by some other software. You can check the description of the same on MDN. This isn't specific to Safari, Chrome on Windows does the same thing, but somehow it looks like Chrome on Mac behaves differently.

In general it wouldn't be a good idea to have the stream being accessed by two apps at the same time, since this could lead to accidental sharing of stream during confidential recordings/meeting.

Just handle the error and update the UI accordingly to inform the user. I'm still researching on how we can detect "camera in use" or "screen in use" cross browser and will share if I find something.

[Reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#:%7E:text=Thrown%20if%2C%20although%20the%20user%20granted%20permission%20to%20use%20the%20matching%20devices%2C%20a%20hardware%20error%20occurred%20at%20the%20operating%20system%2C%20browser%2C%20or%20Web%20page%20level%20which%20prevented%20access%20to%20the%20device)